# Delete statement in Asp.net and sql

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a web form having 3 drop down list for fiscal year,fiscal period and customer group and a delete button .when i select 2011,10 and k-12 respectively from all drop down list and click button .it becomes fail to delete the records from underlying table.there are 111806 data for those combination in the database table.there is no problem with the logic that i use for deletion process because all other records are for other criteria deleted successfully.
I have got this exception-
"Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."
I have no idea about this.please help.

Comment: I have also set the timeout property of server to 0.but still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to perform this query manually? How long does it work? Check timeout settings of your SQL connection.

Comment: I have try it manually from sql server and get deleted all the records within 1 min.i have already set the timeout property to '0'.

Comment: And still receiving timeouts? "CommandTimeout  has no effect when the command is executed against a context connection (a SqlConnection opened with "context connection=true" in the connection string)." (c) MSDN

Comment: there are certain conditions, when timeout setting is ignored. I mentioned at least one such condition.